# R data.table 'by' behavior when using expression

Tags: r, data.table

I stumbled upon a peculiar behavior while using 'by' in data table. It would be great if someone can explain the below behavior

I am just summing a column values into two buckets of positive and negative.

```
dt = data.table(a=sample(letters, 100, replace=T), b= (-49:50), c=(-49:50))
```

all of the below work

```
dt[, sum(b), by=as.logical(b>0)];
dt[, sum(b), by=as.factor(b>0)];
compFun = function(x,y) x>y; dt[, sum(b), by=compFunc(b,0)];
#FALSE -1225
#TRUE  1275
```

but this doesnt

```
dt[, sum(b), by=(b>0)];
#TRUE   1
#FALSE  0
```

Looks like .SD doesnt have column 'b' in the last case.
What am I missing here? Isn't this inconsistent behavior?

thanks

Comment: It seems to work on devel version

Comment: This was [bug #497](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/497), and was recently fixed in the [devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/497).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
dt[, names(.BY), by=(b>0)]
#        b V1
# 1: FALSE  b
# 2:  TRUE  b
```

vs

```
dt[, names(.BY), by=I(b>0)]
#        I V1
# 1: FALSE  I
# 2:  TRUE  I
```

I think in the first case it overwrites the variable `b` and as a result  when you call `dt[, sum(b), by=(b>0)]` it sums the `BY` variable rather than the column `b` of the data table...

Comment: Yes. It used to, because the column name extracted from the expression was `b`. The way to get around is to name the `by-expression`. But in 1.9.5, these cases are now caught, and column names aren't simplified in those cases.